# How to set a starting day in heatmap (python)?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, heatmap

I have drawn a heatmap that represents the anomaly score value for a specific week and its days. The heatmap I got is shown below.
[image]

Now, on the Y-axis, I want the day that should start with Monday and on the x-axis, the gap between the two dates should be 7 days i.e. one week. Is there any other way to draw a heatmap to get the results I desired? Or is there any other ways to set the parameters in the existing heatmap function (sns.heatmap())?

Comment: Can you paste a copyable dataframe for us to be able to create this heatmap on our end, then we can tweak that and help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more sophisticated way to do this, but I have taken the day of the week values from the sample data dates and pivot transformed them to be the source data for the graph.

[image]

Next, we will create a list of days of the week to make the day of the week data into day names. Then, create a label for the x-axis with a date interval of 7 days.

```
weekday = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']

ax = sns.heatmap(df_pivot, cmap='afmhot_r')

freq = 7
ax.set_xticks(df.index[::freq])
ax.set_xticklabels(df.iloc[::freq]["date"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

ax.set_yticklabels(weekday, rotation=0)
ax.invert_yaxis()

plt.show()
```

[image]